# clock source in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, clock

In a system running kernel version 2.6.38 I see this sysfs file which shows the current clock source (happens to be tsc) /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource

But looks like this sysfs file was introduced recently. In 2.6.9 I don't see this file. In versions that doesn't have this sysfs is there an easy to see the clock source ? When I compare the clock_gettime() ouptputs in these versions 2.6.9 seems to be at microseconds granularity and 2.6.38 is at nanoseconds granularity. Hence wondering what the clock source in 2.6.9 is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try grepping clocksource and TSC from dmesg output.

FWIW, the high-resolution timers (which enabled nanosecond resolution, among many other things) were introduced in the 2.6.21 kernel or thereabouts; older kernels don't have that, as you have found out.

Comment: time.c: Using 14.318180 MHz HPET timer.
time.c: Detected 2527.119 MHz processor. This is what I see in dmesg. Does this mean clock source is HPET ?

Comment: Yes, in your case clock source is HPET. But why do you ask? Why don't you use the `clock_getres` function?